# Cannot access/update variable in flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I have a flask app.py setup like to

```
def init():
  return pickle.load(open('./foo.pkl','rb'))

foo = init()
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)


@app.route('/foo',methods=['POST'])
def getFoo():
  return foo

@app.route('/foo',methods=['PUT'])
@app.errorhandler(400)
@app.errorhandler(500)
def updateFoo():
  args_map = request.get_json()
  if 'foo' not in args_map:
    return 'ERROR: Foo not found in request url',400
  foo = args_map.get('foo')
  return 'success!',200
```

But it shows the variable in grey as shown below
[image]

Upon hovering over it, it shows me the following error-
**"foo" is not accessedPylance
(variable) foo: Any**

Is the variable not getting updated? I have tried declaring foo as nonlocal within the update API but that does not work...

Comment: You need to use global rather than nonlocal scope.